# identifying the functional dependencies

Tags: database, database-design, diagram, functional-dependencies

I have been reading up on database design and I am having some difficulty constructing  functional dependency diagrams from tables.

I have the following table.
Each salesperson is identified by a salesperson’s number, and their sales activities are recorded for each month in the table.

[image: table]

I have made the following assumptions:

- Each Salesperson has a unique salesperson number
- Each Client has a unique client number
- Each product has a unique product number and description
- Each Customer has a unique sales persons that they deal with.

I have come up with the following functional dependencies diagram:

[image: graph]

My questions are:

- First of all is this correct way of creating a fd diagram?
- Is this correct based upon the assumptions?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1):

Functional dependencies aren't usually expressed in a diagram. Instead, they're usually expressed like this . . .

```
A->B
B->CD
```

or like this.

```
"Salesperson number" -> "Salesperson name"
"Client number" -> "Client name"
```

If your diagram means that "Product number" -> "Quantity sold", then your diagram is wrong. Also, client number does not determine product number.

---

A functional dependency answers the question, "Given one value for A, can I determine one and only one value for B?", where A and B are sets of attributes. Let's look at a simple  example.

Given one value for "Product number", can we determine one and only one value for "Product description"? Yes. Given the product number P1023-01, we can determine only one value for "Product description": "A4 Paper". Product number P1023-01 never matches up with any product name but "A4 Paper".

Given one value for "Product number", can we determine one and only one value for "Quantity sold"? No. Given the product number P1023-01, we can determine two different values for "Quantity sold": 6 and 10. The dependency "Product number" -> "Quantity sold" doesn't hold in this relation.

Comment: Thats the way the guide I am following does FD diagrams . Sorry I meant to imply that each client will have ordered certain products and therefore products is related (arrow wrong way around) to client number.

Comment: Learn an unambiguous notation, regardless of what your "guide" says.

Comment: So Quantity will not appear in the FD digram?

Comment: "Quantity sold" will appear in the diagram; it's just not functionally dependent on "Product number". It *looks* like it *might* be functionally dependent on {"Month", "Salesperson number", "Client number", "Product number"}, but there might be other sets of attributes that determine "Quantity sold", too.

Comment: S#, C#, P# —> Quantity Sold  ?

Comment: Probably not. That would imply that a client would always buy the same quantity of a particular product no matter which month we look at. The sample data might support that notion, but common sense does not.