# Normalisation: im new to db normalisation. I dont know if my answer is right

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

Normalise the following up to 3NF:

projnum | projname | empnum | empname | jobclass | chrghour | hours |

```
    15 |Evergreen|   103   |  June    |Engineer | 84      |  23  |
    15 |Evergreen|   101   |  John    |Designer | 105     |  19  |
    15 |Evergreen|   105   |  Alie    |Designer | 105     |  35  |
    15 |Evergreen|   106   |  Dave    |Analyst  | 96      |  12  |
    15 |Evergreen|   102   |  Anne    |Clerical | 26      |  23  |
```

Edit:

```
Functional dependency 1: projnum → projname

FD2: empnum → empname

FD3: empnum, empname → jobclass

FD4: jobclass → chrghour

FD5: projnum, empnum → hours
```

1NF I get:

```
Table 1(projnum[pk], projname, hours)
Table 2(projnum[pk], empnum[pk], empname, jobclass, chrghour)
```

2NF I get:

```
Table 1(projnum[pk], projname, hours)
Table 2(projnum[pk], empnum[pk])
Table 3(empnum[pk], empname, jobclass, chrghour)
```

3NF I get:

```
Table 1(projnum[pk], projname) //then i put [hours] in table 2 but I DONT KNOW THE LOGIC BEHIND. Explanation is welcomed.
Table 2(Projnum[pk], empnum[pk], hours)
Table 3(empnum[pk], empname, jobclass)
Table 4(jobclass[pk], chrghour)
```

Is there any violation of the rule of the normal forms? Is my answer correct?

Comment: Normalization through BCNF is based on functional dependencies. Edit your question, and include the functional dependencies.

Comment: Functional dependencies added, but im confused...should we list ALL FDs in the 2nd normal form itself?

Comment: Normalization is based on all the FDs you know. You should include all the FDs you know. The sentence "Should we list ALL FDs in the 2nd normal form itself?" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Are you sure that projname -> projnum is not a functional dependency? And empnum, empname -> jobclass would simplify to empnum -> jobclass, wouldn't it?

Comment: empnum → jobclass? Hmm, but if you see the related UNF data above, 2 empnums, 101, 105, have the same jobclass of 'designer'.  Hence it is not fully dependent on the empnums.

Should be both empnum and empname...

Or is my mind going haywire? :|

Comment: And yes i am almost sure projname → projnum is not a FD.

Comment: a) You've misunderstood [what *functional dependency* means](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27000905/562459). b) If you're "almost sure", you're guessing. Are you guessing? (We sometimes have to guess in the real world of database design, but it's a really bad way to learn normalization.)

Comment: Guess i have to recheck my notes :) Thank you, and not im not guessing but im not 100% sure either...but, is my 3NF correct? :s

Comment: If you're not guessing, you can just read the FDs from the text of the homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your 3NF result is correct but your path toward it is, eurhm, hopeless.

The process of normalization is a process of *decomposition* ("splitting").  What is important to understand is that you start off with a *single* relation schema, and *all* the FDs that you have apply to that schema.  What is also important to understand is that at all times during the normalization process, some particular set of FDs applies to one single relation schema.  So after you have split your initial single schema into two relation schemas, you *ALSO* end up with two distinct sets of FDs, each applying to *exactly one* of the relations schemas after the split.  It may even be the case that by doing some particular schema split, you *lose* every ability to express some particular FD that applies to the schema-before-split.  You have done exactly that to FD5 in the first split you did.  FD5 is not expressible in Table1 because empnum is missing in that schema, and it is not expressible in Table2 because hours is missing in that schema.  So FD5 has become inexpressible altogether.  (This is not always avoidable, and therefore not necessarily a bad thing, but in your case it is.)

The fact that you can *only keep splitting further and further*, is why your decomposition process is flawed.  You cannot "move [hours] to Table2".

Comment: Decomposition is of course *a* method of normalization but it isn't the only one. It's perfectly possible to achieve a normalized database design through procedures that don't involve any decomposition at all. IMO it's a bit unfortunate that students are still taught normalization as a linear process of decomposition through successive normal forms. I'm not convinced that it's the best way to each database design concepts.

Comment: @sqlvogel, if you are referring to the concept of getting a design in 5NF from the get-go, based on just intuition/experience/common sense/..., yes, I am quite aware of that "method" and I'm also quite aware that it often produces good results in quite a smaller amount of time than the "textbook" normalization-by-decomposition method.  However, if the textbook method is all you're *allowed* to do (usually the case in textbook courses) then decomposition is all you got.

Answer (score 0):

More information about the meaning of your data is needed; some answers appear wrong, but which ones is impossible to tell. Specifically:

- If `hours` is the duration of a project it belongs in a
  project table, like in the 2NF answer; if it is the time an employee
  worked on a project it belongs in the many-to-many relationship table
  between projects and employees, like in the 3NF answer.
- Can the same employee appear with different `chrghour` and/or `jobclass` values?

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: No, same employee cannot appear with a different chrghour or jobclass, but they can appear with different [hours].